# How do we update the value to the specific row in LWC? and also what if I do mass update for all the rows?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

```
<template for:each={myList} for:item="foreCast" for:index="indexVar">
    <tr key={foreCast.id}>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
            <div class="slds-align_absol[![enter image description here][1]][1]ute-center">
                <lightning-formatted-date-time value={foreCast.Start_Date__c} time-zone="UTC">
                </lightning-formatted-date-time>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning-formatted-date-time value={foreCast.End_Date__c} time-zone="UTC">
                </lightning-formatted-date-time>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning-formatted-number value={foreCast.Straight_line_Revenue_In_Euro__c} format-style="currency"
                    currency-code="EUR"></lightning-formatted-number>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning-input key={foreCast.Id} data-id={foreCast.Id} name="input1" label="Name"
                    value={foreCast.Projected_Revenue_In_Euro__c} variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-input>

                <!--onchange={allSelected}-->
            </div>
        </td>
        <td data-label="Account Name">
            <div class="slds-align_absolute-center">
                <lightning-input type="checkbox" checked={foreCast.Preserve_Projected_Revenue__c}
                    value={foreCast.Preserve_Projected_Revenue__c} data-id={foreCast.Id} onblur={handleCheckBoxChange}>
                </lightning-input>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

In HTML you are providing the Id of the record in data-id attribute, similarly, you can provide the API Name of the field in the "name" attribute so that in handleChange handler you can update the specific field of the specific record in your myList.

In js :

```
  handleChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.name); //... Field API Name
        console.log(event.target.value); //... value
        console.log(event.target.dataset.id); //...Record Id

        // Now you can loop over your myList and update the value of the specific field in that particular record
        // myList[i][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a nice approach to this problem

```
<!--cmp.html-->
...
<tr data-id={row.id} onchange={handleChange}>
  ...
  <td><lightning-input name="Name" value={row.name}></lightning-input></td>
  <td><lightning-input name="Age" value={row.age}></lightning-input></td>
</tr>
...
```

```
// cmp.js
// ...
onChange(event) {
  myList[event.currentTarget.dataset.id][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
}
// ...
```

This way you can specify handler and data-id only once and save yourself time and nerves)